# How to create a horizontal UL which shows 3 items per line?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a horizontal UL which always shows 3 items per line. The tricky part is that the items can be of varying widths. For example:

```
<ul class="items">
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox" id="work" />
    Work items
   </li>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox" id="shopping" /> 
    Shopping
    </li>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox" id="financial" />
    Financial Information & Tips
    </li>
</ul>
```

etc.

I want to do it so its essentially like using a table, where it always shows 3 items per line, and the checkbox of each item is always on the same line as its text.

How can I do it?

Here's the current code I'm using, but it doesn't show the items evenly, often the last checkbox ends up on line 1 and the text is pushed to the next line.

```
ul.items
{
  text-align: center; 
  list-style-type: none;  
  width: 400px;
}

ul.items li
{
    display: inline;     
}
```

Comment: Would having a ul with inline-block il elements every 3 items have worked for you? That is, only have 3 li elements for each ul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use float for this

```
ul.items
{
  text-align: center; 
  list-style-type: none;  
  width: 400px;
}

ul.items li
{
    float: left; 
    display: inline;     
}

.clear { clear: both; }
```

with this html:

```
<ul class="items">
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox" id="work" />
    Work items
   </li>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox" id="shopping" /> 
    Shopping
    </li>
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox" id="financial" />
    Financial Information & Tips
    </li>
  <li class="clear"></li>
</ul>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hG3Us/

Comment: Mate you cannot put <div> in <ul>

Answer (score 14):

Try the CSS `nth-child` selector. Works regardless of the width.

I also removed your `display:inline` rule and replaced it with a `float:left;`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VmV3y/1/)**

```
ul.items li:nth-child(3n+4) {
  clear:left;
  float:left;
}
```

For more info on `nth-child`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: This is causing a line break to appear on: 4th, 7th, 10th, and 13th elements. Not good.

Comment: It displays three items per line as you specified. Also, it inserts no line breaks. Did you try the fiddle?